# How to colour radio buttons?

Tags: swift, cocoa, colors, appkit, nsbutton

[image]

You can see that Apple has coloured the radio buttons. I would like to do the same. I can't seems to find the option to change the colour in Interface Builder on storyboard.

As for doing it, programmatically, I tried enabling layer `.wantsLayer = true` and then tried to set the colour by `.layer?.borderColour = NSColor.systemBlue.cgColor` and tried `.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemRed.cgColor` and other similar properties but no avail.

Likewise, how do you add the colour rectangles on `NSMenuItem` on `NSPopUpButton`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates a group of custom radio buttons for MacOS made by subclassing NSButton.  It may be run in an Xcode swift project by copy/pasting into a newly added file called ‘main.swift’ and deleting the original AppDelegate.

```
import Cocoa

class CustomButton: NSButton {

var circleColor: NSColor!

override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
 let circle = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)
 switch(self.tag) {
  case 0:
   circleColor = NSColor.red
  case 1:
   circleColor = NSColor.green
  case 2:
   circleColor = NSColor.yellow
  case 3:
   circleColor = NSColor.orange
  default:
   break
 }
  circleColor.set()
  circle.fill()

  if(self.state) == .on {
   let dotRect = NSInsetRect(bounds, 18.0, 18.0);
   let dot = NSBezierPath (ovalIn:dotRect)
   let dotColor = NSColor.black
   dotColor.set()
   dot.fill()
  }
 }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
 var window: NSWindow!

@objc func radioGrpAction(_ sender:NSButton) {
 print("You selected: id = \(sender.tag)")
}

func buildMenu() {
let mainMenu = NSMenu()
NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
// **** App menu **** //
let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
let appMenu = NSMenu()
appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")
}
    
func buildWnd() {
    
 let _wndW : CGFloat = 300
 let _wndH : CGFloat = 200
 window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Radio Button Group"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// === Radio Grp Box === //
 let grpBox = NSBox(frame: NSMakeRect( 50,_wndH - 100, 150, 60))
 grpBox.title = "Radio Group"
 window.contentView!.addSubview (grpBox)
 // === Radio Horizontal Grid === //
 let _btnW : CGFloat = 24
 let _btnH : CGFloat = 24
 let _left : CGFloat = 10 // left margin first button
 let _YOffset : CGFloat = 5 // 0,0 at left, bottom of group box
 let _spacing : CGFloat = 5 // spacing between buttons

 for x in stride(from:0, through:3, by:1) {
 let _XOffset = _left + CGFloat(x)*(_btnW + _spacing)
 let btn = CustomButton(frame:NSMakeRect(_XOffset, _YOffset, _btnW, _btnH))
 btn.setButtonType(.radio)
 btn.tag = x
 if(x == 0){btn.state = .on}
 btn.action = #selector(self.radioGrpAction(_:))
 grpBox.contentView!.addSubview(btn)
}

// === Quit btn === //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// ***** main.swift ***** //
let app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```

[image: radioGrp]

Comment: Could you please show me how it supposed to look? It looks nothing like a radio button. I got an oval shape and it looks completely different.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot! I can't get the radio button to look like your screenshot. I created a test Xcode project. Added a radio button on a view controller and added the subclass CustomButton via Interface Builder and it looks nothing like your screenshot.

Comment: It's a stand alone demo; needs to be run from 'main.swift' file in Xcode swift project.

Comment: I got your code working as it is. But I would like to use it in an actual app with the `AppDelegate.swift` file. What I am saying is that I copied the `CustomButton` and added it to a radio button as a subclass on storyboard through Interface Builder. `CustomButton` subclass should work in any project.

Comment: If you find it useful could you please give me credit by checking as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the same but for AppKit:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit

extension NSView {
    
    func centerX(inView view: NSView, constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
    }
    
    func centerY(inView view: NSView, constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
    }
    
    func setDimensions(height: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }
}

class CustomRadioButton: NSView {
    
    private let containerSize: CGFloat = 60.0
    private let selectorSize: CGFloat = 20.0
    
    var containerColor: NSColor = .blue
    var selectorColor: NSColor = .red
    
    var selected: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            selectorView.isHidden = !selected
        }
    }
    
    private lazy var containerView: NSView = {
        
        let view = NSView()
        
        view.wantsLayer = true
        
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = containerColor.cgColor
        
        return view
        
    }()
    
    private lazy var selectorView: NSView = {
        
        let view = NSView()
        view.wantsLayer = true
        
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = selectorColor.cgColor
        
        return view
        
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerSize, height: containerSize))
        
        configureUI()
    
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
    private func configureUI() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.setDimensions(height: containerSize, width: containerSize)
        containerView.layer?.cornerRadius = containerSize / 2
        containerView.centerX(inView: self)
        containerView.centerY(inView: self)
        
        addSubview(selectorView)
        
        selectorView.setDimensions(height: selectorSize, width: selectorSize)
        selectorView.layer?.cornerRadius = selectorSize / 2
        selectorView.centerY(inView: containerView)
        selectorView.centerX(inView: containerView)
        
    }
    
    
}

let selector = CustomRadioButton()

selector.selected = false
```